# Orientation changes disrupt the frames of my buttons

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a small set of buttons that have rounded edges based on their frame height/2. When the device rotates, the frames become misshapen until any button is pressed. Is there a way I can prevent this? Why is this happening? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here's some code. Sorry, could have included that initially:

```
 for button in buttons {
        button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 1
        button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.width / 2
 }
```

I call this during ViewDidLayoutSubviews.

Comment: Some code is needed. I have 100x100 buttons on my initial screen with rounded corners that work just fine. I also use auto layout. Please post relevant code - and please show if you are using auto layout. Thanks.

Comment: @dfd Sorry about that. Just updated the original post. I am using auto-layout, yes.